# cannot connect to cpanel database

Tags: php, sql, cpanel

I have made an sql database in cpanel and adding some data to a table. I am now trying to access it and print out the data on my website, but I am not convinced I have the php correct. A tutorial I found to explain it is using xampp and not a real online website. so far I have a database handler php file with,

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "username";
$dbPassword = "password";
$dbName = "databasename";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

In my index.php file I have,

```
<?php

include_once('php/db_handler.php');

?>

//some html code

    <?php
    //Choose all fields in table
    $sql ="SELECT * users;";

    //var to put in all the results
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    //var to get the number of rows returned.
    $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    //if the number of rows returned is not empty, then cycle through all results and print the stated ones to the screen.
    if($resultcheck > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['$email, $username'];
        }
    }
    ?>




  //more html code
```

I am not totally sure what I should be using for database server name, In cpanel there is a section with server info and it gives me the servername webhosting2004, I have tried this also which does not work.

The username and password are as per the user details in mysql databases (using my cpanel accountname_name)

I get the following on the error log

```
[05-Nov-2019 12:31:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'dannyjeb_admin'@'old' (using password: YES) in /home/dannyjeb/public_html/php/db_handler.php on line 8
[05-Nov-2019 12:31:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/dannyjeb/public_html/test.php on line 48
[05-Nov-2019 12:31:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/dannyjeb/public_html/test.php on line 51
```

Comment: check if you are connecting to the right port

Answer (score 0):

You can start by displaying connection errors to determine if the connection works

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

Second. Make sure you have remote access to your database allowed.
If not, allow it. To do this, go to RemoteMysql from cPanel and add `%.%` to allow users from any origin.

Third. If you are not sure about the user for the database connection, you can always create a new MySQL user to use for your connection.

Comment: Thanks. using the %.% has worked but I have read that using wildcards isn't best practice? It doesn't particularly matter in this situation as this is just a test for myself. But would you still use this is the db had sensitive information?

Comment: @DannyJebb True, it depends, if you have like only 1 backend that connects, then you can do for example a specific user and specific origin `'api_user@123.123.123.132'`, for one user but multiple origins `'api_user@%'` and for all users and all origins `'%@%'`. If it's really sensitive information, then you should only allow the localhost to connect with your database and prevent any remote access, since you shouldn't connect with your live database from localhost for example.